# how to convert a certain number to hours/minutes?

Tags: java, timing

Hello everyone well i have a certain long number and i wish to divide it and show how many minutes and hours remaining :

```
timeToReceive = Utils.currentTimeMillis() + (60 * 1000 * 60 * 8); // 8 hours
```

here is my timeToReceive long.

I want to show how much time is remaining for the timeToReceive(it's set for 8 hours in the future).

So i do this :

```
(timeToReceive - Utils.currentTimeMillis()) / (1000 * 60)
```

this displays it in minutes, however i want to display it in hours and minutes, how will i go bout doing that?

thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: @Mumfi i don't know that's why I'm asking lol.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about lack of understanding of basic arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

```
timeInMinutes = (timeToReceive - Utils.currentTimeMillis()) / (1000 * 60);

hours = timeInMinutes / 60;
minutes=timeInMinutes % 60;
```

This works fine

Answer (score 0):

First count the time in minutes

```
minutes = (timeToReceive - Utils.currentTimeMillis()) / (1000 * 60)
```

Then use / operation and % operation

```
minutes / 60; // will just divide and truncate - gives you hours
minutes % 60; // will give you the rest that is left after dividing - the part that was truncated when you used / operator
```